# Autolayout Constraint to UITextView to wrap text around UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

I am trying to achieve something like mentioned in the image below,

[image]

Here we have two components,

1. UIImageView &
2. UITextView

   *Is there a way to wrap the text of UITextView to wrap around the UIImageView,* **using Autolayout**?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

It is shown in one of the raywenderlich.com youtube tutorial channels. You could find it here,
https://youtu.be/m6mvOmPYNA8?t=13m53s

Comment: Not possible using autolayout. However you can use another API as specified here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332928/xcode-swift-how-to-wrap-text-around-image

Comment: @ZeMoon I have edited my question with the video link where the same is implemented. Seems like it is possible.

Comment: Here's your solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/22226022/1436617 … I tried this and it works.